# How to create self-referential AST in Rust?

Tags: recursion, rust, abstract-syntax-tree, self-reference, recursive-datastructures

Let's imagine we have a very simple AST for programming language with only functions and calls

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Function {
    pub body: Vec<Call>
}

struct Call {
    pub function: Arc<Function> 
}
```

Now we want to recursively call functions:

```rust
let f = Arc::new(Function { body: vec![Call {function: f.clone()}] }) 
// Doesn't work, as we haven't created Arc yet
```

```
let mut f = Arc::new(Function { body: vec![] });
f.body.push(Call { function: f.clone() })
// Doesn't work, because Arc has immutable data
```

The problem can be solved using `Arc<Mutex<_>>` or `Arc<RwLock<_>>` in `Call`:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock}

struct Call {
    pub function: Arc<RwLock<Function>> 
}
```

And then creating with:

```
let f = Arc::new(RwLock::new(Function { body: vec![] }));
f.write().unwrap().body.push(Call { function: f.clone() })
```

But now you need to always write `f.write().unwrap()` or `f.read().unwrap()` everywhere, even though function is mutable **only on construction**.

Can you do something better than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Weak.html) for the parent pointer. You need to do that anyway to allow for proper destruction. Then use [`Arc::new_cyclic()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.new_cyclic):

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};

struct Function {
    pub body: Vec<Call>,
}

struct Call {
    pub function: Weak<Function>,
}

let f = Arc::new_cyclic(|f| Function {
    body: vec![Call {
        function: Weak::clone(f),
    }],
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to propagate errors (`Result`) inside `new_cyclic`?

Comment: @gavrilikhin.d Apparently not... But see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/75861#issuecomment-980455381. Also, in the worst case, you can have a `Result` variable, set it to error in the closure and check it after.